# Do function decorators in python call the decorated function implicitly?

Tags: python, function, decorator, function-object

My title could be misleading. my question comes from this code snippet.

```
class myDecorator(object):

    def __init__(self, f):
        print "inside myDecorator.__init__()"
        f() # Prove that function definition has completed

    def __call__(self):
        print "inside myDecorator.__call__()"

@myDecorator
def aFunction():
    print "inside aFunction()"

print "Finished decorating aFunction()"

#aFunction()
```

when I execute, the above code, I get the output as

```
inside myDecorator.__init__()
inside aFunction()
Finished decorating aFunction()
```

however, I thought the output should only be

```
Finished decorating aFunction()
```

just decorating the function, calls the constructor and executes myDecorator object.I was under the impression that only when `aFunction()` is called, the decorator pattern is executed. why is it so?

Another question about decorator:

This [link](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808) explains the decorator as `@ is just a little syntax sugar meaning "pass a function object through another function and assign the result to the original function.`

what is the function object, another function and original function that this refers to?

Comment: It is not called implicitly, but you call it explicitly in your init: `f()`. Before `aFunction` can be passed to an instance of `myDecorator` obviously this instance needs to be created an initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "function object" is `aFunction`. The "another function" is `myDecorator`. The "original function" should actually read "original function *name*", and would be "aFunction" in this case.

```
def aFunction(...)
   ...

aFunction = myDecorator(aFunction)
```